# nginx: '/' url doesn't try index.html file

Tags: nginx

With this configuration, when I call "`my.domainname.com/unity/index.html`" manually, it works *and* it finds all the other files.
When I try "`my.domainname.com/unity/`" it doesnt go to the default index.html file and returns a 403. What am I missing?

(most important are the latest lines, configuring when user wants to access to `/unity` path)

```
server {
  listen *:443 ssl;
  server_name "~^my\.domainname\..*$";

  index index.html index.htm;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/proxy-access.log proxylog;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/proxy-error.log error;

  ssl_certificate /var/lib/acme/live/my.domainname.com/fullchain;
  ssl_certificate_key /var/lib/acme/live/my.domainname.com/privkey;
  ssl_trusted_certificate /var/lib/acme/live/hive.battlesoop.fr/chain;
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;

  location '/.well-known/acme-challenge' {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Server $host;
    proxy_pass http://acmetool;
  }

  # Add CORS access to all = '*'
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept' always;
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;

  # unity
  location ~* ^/unity(?<p>.*) {
    root /web/htdocs/my.domainname.com/unity;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files /$p =403;
    access_log off;
    expires 1h;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `try_files` the `index` feature is triggered by a *file* term with a trailing `/`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

I couldn't get it working with your named capture though, but if you knock the "/unity" term off the end of the `root` statement, you can use the conventional approach.

For example:

```
location ~* ^/unity {
    root /web/htdocs/my.domainname.com;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =403;
    access_log off;
    expires 1h;
}
```

Comment: What is the `$uri` term replaced by exactly?

Comment: The current URI being processed by the location. See [this link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_uri).